# Replacing Images With Text

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am trying to write a Greasemonkey script that will take a web page that has a series of un-ID'ed linked images and replace them with bolded text.

The path I was taking has unfortunately lead to a couple of dead ends.

First, the code I have for some reason replaces the image with the [CLICK] text, and then immediately runs through the parent/replace again and erases the [CLICK].

Second, I now have the sneaking suspicion that there's no good way to bold that createTextNode.

So could someone #1 explain why that loop wasn't working for me, and #2 tell me the right way to do this so that I can have the added text be bold.

```
var smiliesList = document.evaluate(
"//img[contains(@src,'smilies')]", document.body, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null); 

var prefixReplace = document.createTextNode('[CLICK]');
var prefixImgSrc = ('smilies/goofyimage.png')


for (var i=0;i<smiliesList.snapshotLength;i++) {

    var node = smiliesList.snapshotItem(i);

        if (node.src == prefixImgSrc) {

            node.parentNode.replaceChild(prefixReplace, node); 


    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how easy the **whole script** is with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

// smilies/goofyimage.png is case-sensitive
var goofyImages = $("img[src*='smilies/goofyimage.png']");

goofyImages.replaceWith ("<b>[CLICK]</b>");
```

This uses:

- [jQuery's Attribute Contains Selector](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=attribute-contains-selector)
- [jQuery's `replaceWith()`](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=replaceWith)

Comment: Here's how easy the whole script is with **"Oh my god thank you."**

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to create a new replacement text node for each image while you're in the loop. You're currently only creating a single node prior to the loop.

Also, to create bold text, just create a `<b>` element and then use `innerHTML` to put text inside.

```
var smiliesList = document.evaluate(
"//img[contains(@src,'smilies')]", document.body, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null); 

var len = smiliesList.snapshotLength;

for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
  var node = smiliesList.snapshotItem(i),
      p;

    if (node.src.indexOf('smilies/goofyimage.png') > -1) {
      var textNode = document.createElement('b');
      textNode.innerHTML = '[CLICK]';    

      if (node.parentNode) {
        p = node.parentNode;
        p.removeChild(node);
        p.appendChild(textNode);              
      }      
  }
}
```

Also, I couldn't help but think there may be a better way of doing this. I'd recommend going with this version - fewer lines of code and more browser compatibility:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');        
for (var i = imgs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (imgs[i].src.indexOf('smilies/goofyimage.png') > -1) {
      var textNode = document.createElement('b');
      textNode.innerHTML = '[CLICK]';    
      imgs[i].parentNode.replaceChild(textNode, imgs[i]);     
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Putting the node inside the loop fixed the first half, but the replaceChild is balking at the fact that (I think?) the textNode element isn't really a node.

Comment: Just updated. Switched from `replaceChild` to `removeChild` and then `appendChild` which may be better. If that doesn't do it, probably need to see the HTML.

Comment: Close, but you should test your code. You'll find that it crashes (trying to use `node` after it's been removed), and that it would otherwise scramble the position of the (ex) images about.